# Why does HtmlButton object.click() not work in HtmlUnit?

Tags: eclipse, junit4, htmlunit

i got htmlbutton from one html+javascipt page but my code does not work(JUnit+HtmlUnit in Eclipse)
The code is :

```
final HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(url);
final HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("registrationForm");
final HtmlButton button=(HtmlButton)page.getElementById("submit1"); 

final HtmlTextInput phone = form.getInputByName("phoneno");

phone.setValueAttribute("1234567890");

// Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.

final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();  //this doesn't work
final String pageAsXml = page2.asText();
System.out.println(pageAsXml);
```

the line commented "this doesn't work" has some problem.there is no error but it isn't working.
is there any problem with webclient constructor? do we need to specify browser version as argument? will this work in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

```
final HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(url);
final HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("registrationForm");
final HtmlButton button=(HtmlButton)form.getElementById("submit1"); 
//instead of page try using the form
final HtmlTextInput phone = form.getInputByName("phoneno");

phone.setValueAttribute("1234567890");

// Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.

final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();  //this doesn't work
final String pageAsXml = page2.asText();
System.out.println(pageAsXml);

//Let me know if it works.
```